# KDE-Openbox closes immediately after it opens on Cygwin

Tags: windows, kde, openbox, cygwin

I just installed Cygwin a few days ago. Now when I want to explore it, I can't run KDE-Openbox. I haven't tried anything else, except compiling Mplayer which did work.

Last time I had Cygwin installed and I posted a question here about not being able to run programs in it, I deleted the question after getting no answers. I thought I had figured it out: Norton 360 was finding viruses on every install and is set to remove it automatically. I learned that this is common, and the fix was to disable Norton antivirus protection while unpacking the archives, then enable it again and scan after the install. I thought this would then be the reason for Cygwin never working, but maybe that's not the case.

I installed all Cygwin packages, and didn't have Norton remove any packages while installing.

I started KDE-Openbox from the Windows start menu. I'm assuming KDE-Openbox starts its own X server. I've tried both with X server already running and without.

Comment: How are you starting X? Did you really install [everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230657/what-is-the-current-full-install-size-of-cygwin/21233990#21233990)? [Norton is BLODA](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda) 100% of the time, not just during installation of Cygwin.

Comment: No. The rebase fix and remove Norton Completely doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: That's why I posted that as a comment, not an answer: It is just a fact. I had no reason to believe it would solve your specific problem, today, just a lot of history to show that it causes problems. Whether your invasive antimalware package solves more problems for you than it causes is up to you.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Thank's for the info, I'm still learning. Sometimes it's a bit daunting to know and have the oversight, I use most my time learning and reading about the functions of Linux, so when using Windows, I just expect things to work. It is entirely to explore and try programs I'm using Cygwin. I set to become familiar with Linux and learn that.

Comment: I will add though, maybe in my ignorance, but I've found at least 5 viruses with Norton the last four years on different pc's.